# How can I symbolize and reuse a regular expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want to do like this, reuse tokenized expression in another declaration (like in lex)

```
digit = [0-9]
integer (0|([1-9]{digit}*))
```

Can I define and reuse regular expression like this way in python?

Comment: try f-string, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281007/how-can-i-symbolize-and-reuse-regular-expression-in-python#comment120676375_68281007), you can do something like this:

```
digit = re.compile('[0-9]')
integer = re.compile(f'(0|[1-9]{digit.pattern})')
```

You can retrieve the pattern string from the [`pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.pattern) attribute, which allows you to combine arbitrary regexes. If you want to use strings, it's even simpler:

```
digit = '[0-9]'
integer = f'(0|[1-9]{digit})'
```